# Remove files from app engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have uploaded files to app engine which I wish to remove since they are not required to run my app in production.

How do I remove them. I have already included them in the skip_files section in app.yaml.

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
- ^(.*/)?.*/node_modules/.*$
- ^(.*/)?.*/client_libs/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\.bowerrc$
- ^(.*/)?\.bower.json$
- ^(.*/)?\.gulpfile.js$
- ^(.*/)?\.package.json$
- ^(.*/)?\.requirements.txt$
```

But I see them in the set of deployed files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Putting files in skip_files section only mean it is going to be skipped, when app is running. It doesn't mean that it is deleted it is showing in 
deployed files because it is there on live server.

To delete the files that is not required:

**First:**
you should deploy a new version that does not contain those files.

**Second:**
Use `appspot admin console` to set this as the default version.

**Finally:**
Delete the old version.